# Namespaces of Nodes

Tags: ros, namespace, nodes, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At first I executed the command `roscore` to activate name service and XMLRPC mechanism for node communation. Then, I launched two turtlesim nodes for turtle simulation which are `turtlesim_node` and `teleop_turtle`.

Finally, I executed the command `rosnode list` to display running nodes in ROS system. The output is demonstrated below.

`/rosout`

`/teleop_turtle`

`/turtlesim`

In this point, a question came to my mind. I have read names and namespaces section of wikiros. I am a little bit familiar with namespace concept.

Can we say that all nodes are located directly under global namespace ?

I am asking this question because when I list running nodes, names of these nodes begin with forward slash ( / ), which means that their namespaces are global namespace itself. Can we make such a generalization ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314560/namespaces-of-nodes/) by [gktg1514](https://answers.ros.org/users/37700/gktg1514/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2019-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can definitely run nodes in namespaces, and it is quite easy in lauch files. To run a node in a namespace, simply add the `ns` attribute to a `<node>` tag. For example:

`<node pkg="foo" type="bar" name="my_node" ns="my_namespace" />`

would run the `bar` node with runtime name `my_node` in the `my_namespace` namespace. Therefore, if you ran `rosnode list` now, you would see `/my_namespace/my_node`.

Running a node in a namespace allows the following:

- You can run multiple instances of a node with the same name, as long as they are in different namespaces
- All topics and services the node advertises or subscribes to are also placed in the same namespace, **as long as there is no leading slash in the topic or service name string**

There are some fancy things you can do with namespaces in launch files, like running a bunch of things in a namespace using `<group>`, or including other launch files and putting everything in those launch files into a namespace. Check out the roslaunch XML syntax documentation for more http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2019-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5